# How can I show macOS desktop on multiple displays

Tags: macos, display

I have multiple monitors that I use with my laptop, and my desktop files (and widgets too now), only show up on the display I designate as primary. Without mirroring my displays, is there a way to make these files appear on all monitors?

Comment: No, there is not.